# Wordpress - How to create redirection in NGINX?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, redirect, config

I have a dilemma. I migrated my wordpress site from Apapache server to NGINX.

In the process I changed permalink in WP from

**/index.php/%postname%/**

to

**/%postname%/**

Now, users coming to site from Google, are getting 404's because of the permalink change. Typically I would just redirect any page via WP plugin, but because of this index.php in the permalink, plugins don't work. So I have no choice but to create a redirection somewhere in NGINX conf file.

Please advise what to do.

Answer (score 0):

In the server configuration file (the file will be located at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`).

If it does not exist there, it may also be at `/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` or `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

For temporary redirect:

```
rewrite ^/oldlocation$ http://www.newdomain.com/newlocation redirect;
```

For permanent redirect:

```
rewrite ^/oldlocation$ http://www.newdomain.com/newlocation permanent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
     rewrite ^/index.php/(.*)$ /$1 permanent;
     ...
}
```